# How to truncate a datatable into a dataset

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I need to delete all rows in a DataTable of a Dataset.
This is my code:

```
For r As Int16 = 0 To mDataset.Tables("MyTable").Rows.Count - 1
    mDataset.Tables("MyTable").Rows.Rows(r).Delete()
Next
```

Is it possible to do this without a loop?

Would it be a good practice deleting and recreating the table?

Comment: depends what you want to do. what is your goal?

Comment: `mDataset.Tables("MyTable").Rows.Clear()`

Comment: @Plutonix That's what I need! I didn't find it on msdn (but I think it was my fault). If you'll post it as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
mDataset.Tables("MyTable").Rows.Clear()
```